# jquery submit button reset

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, reset

I have a form that submits via jquery post.
the result of the query returns text which is populated into a div below the form.

The form works and returns data but the form submit button doesn't 'unclick' or reset.
the jquery code I have tried includes:

```
$( '#my_form' ).each(function(){
    this.reset();
});
```

&

```
$('#my_form')[0].reset();
```

the input text boxes are reset but not the submit button - meaning that the form cant be submitted again, is their a command to reset the submit button such as 'removeAttr('checked')'?

Comment: The submit button is'nt disabled by default when submitting a form with ajax, there is code somewhere in your javascript that does that. Find that code and remove it.

Comment: did you disabled the button after the post was made ??? coz i don't think it gets disabled by default after the form submission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
$('#my_form input:submit').prop('disabled',false);
```